# SSAS Tabular model refresh table structure automatically

Tags: ssas, olap, ssas-tabular, multidimensional-cube

I have an underlying code, which allows users to upload their CSV files and use the data as a dimension in our SSAS Tabular model.
Every time a user uploads a file, the code adds a new column to this table with the name of its corresponding file name and loads the data into it.

so if a user uploads a file called sample1.csv, a column named sample1 is added to this table dynamically and the data is available.
Then this column should be added to the table structure and deployed. Next, the model will be processed and the data would be accessible from Excel.

However I do not know how to automate the part of refreshing the table structure and deploying it (All I know is to do a manual refresh from Visual studio).

I also have access to SQL Agent, Python and SSIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create the XMLA using expression task yourself by feeding a for each loop with column names which can be extracted with a sql task. And then you can run an analysis service DDL task to refresh the structure and finally process
your table